# using SQLite in windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

there is my problem;

I need to use sqlite in my wp8.1 app, i have install the nugets, extensions etc.
I have to save a JSON string into my db.

I know that i have to create a class that i will use to create the table of my sqlite.

Next to that, i know that i have to do a create fct for the table, a insert fct to put my Json string into my table, and a read to get it back and to use that.

I have find tutorial etc and each time i am trying something, it does not work.

I am not a pro in c# and in windows phone 8.1, i am not pro in database. I am in front of a big wall since 3days.

Does anyone can help me plz?

Thank you verry much.

Comment: What did you try? Did you come across any errors?

Comment: @Kulasangar I put the code in a new answer. Thx you

Comment: i can't see any answers!

Answer (score 0):

I have create a Json class for my table;

Here is the code:

```
namespace PhoneApp5.Model
{
    public class Json
    {
          [PrimaryKey]
          public string Key { get; set; } //Key for my table
          public string String { get; set; } //value String Json for my table
    }
}
```

And then i create some fontion to use the table:

```
private async void CreateTable() // create my table
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("blog");
    await conn.CreateTableAsync<Json>();
}

public async void InsertJson(Json json) // insert my Json into my table
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("blog");
    await conn.InsertAsync(json);
}

public async Task<Json> GetJson(string Key) // read my Json string from table
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("blog");

    var query = conn.Table<Json>().Where(x => x.Key == Key);
    var result = await query.ToListAsync();

    return result; // result here is not working because of convertion of System.Connection.Generic.List<PhoneApp5.Model.Json> into PhoneApp5.Model.Json
}

public async void UpdatePost(Json json) // fct update
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("blog");
    await conn.UpdateAsync(json);
}

public async void DeletePost(Json json) // fct delete
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("blog");
    await conn.DeleteAsync(json);
}
```

Then, i don't know what to do.

Thx you for helping

Comment: Which library are you using for your project? And which version?